# whitespace nowrap css for children but not parent

Tags: css, whitespace, styling, nowrap

I have a div with multiple spans inside. The spans contain text that cannot be split over multiple lines so I have set whitespace: nowrap. This does stop the wrapping within each child span correctly but also stop the parent div from wrapping the children so all spans are on a single line that stretches off the page.

How do I change this behaviour so the nowrap only applies to the contents of each span?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 1

```
<style>
   .nowrap { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>

<div>
   <span class="nowrap">span 1</span>
   <span class="nowrap">span 2</span>
   <span class="nowrap">span 3</span>
   <span class="nowrap">span 4</span>
   <span class="nowrap">span 5</span>
</div>
```

Option 2

```
<style>
   .myDiv span{ white-space: nowrap; }
</style>

<div class="myDiv">
   <span>span 1</span>
   <span>span 2</span>
   <span>span 3</span>
   <span>span 4</span>
   <span>span 5</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to avoid having to add the class to every single element. See my answer.

Comment: or give the div an id, and just do 

 id_of_div span{white-spave:nowrap;}

Comment: @Cfreak, I was already thinking that (hence, "Option 1"). I have added Option 2.

Comment: This solution does not work in IE8 or IE9.  See my question http://http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877095

Comment: I'm using option 2 but for some reason my spans all on one line and overflow my div container.

Answer (score 2):

```
div#id-of-parent span {
    whitespace: nowrap;
}
```

That should do the trick. (your div will need the id attribute on it.)

Comment: if you already have an id, there shouldn't be a need for the tag element.

Comment: @Prozaker - true but it's slightly faster for the browser

Answer (score 1):

Set the `span` elements to have `display:inline-block`.